# Android SQLite inserting data in wrong order/ type mismatch

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert data into my db using android and SQLite. When I first did so, I realized I had types the query string in the wrong order, due to which this error popped up. Hence I went into the device file explorer, and deleted the db which was created. Then I fixed the query string and tried again, but the same error pops up. Used the SQLitebrowser too, the schema is correct, but the same error keeps popping up.

This is the java code of `DataBaseHelper` (The one which makes the query string)

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private Context context;
private static final String DB_NAME = "JantaSetu.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Customers";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_COMPLAINT = "Complaint";
private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
private static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "First_Name";
private static final String COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER = "Mobile_Number";



public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + "TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER + "TEXT," +
            COLUMN_COMPLAINT + "TEXT," +
            COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addComplaint(String f_name, String mobile_number, String title, String description)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


    cv.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, f_name);
    cv.put(COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER, mobile_number);
    cv.put(COLUMN_COMPLAINT, title);
    cv.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

This is the code for the activity where I call the function written in DataBaseHelper.java-

```
public class newComplaint extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn_register;
EditText txt_name, txt_mobile_no, txt_title, txt_describe ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_complaint);
    txt_name = findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txt_mobile_no = findViewById(R.id.txt_mobile_no);
    txt_title = findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    txt_describe = findViewById(R.id.txt_describe);

    btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(newComplaint.this);
            db.addComplaint(txt_name.getText().toString().trim(), txt_mobile_no.getText().toString().trim(),
            txt_title.getText().toString().trim(), txt_describe.getText().toString().trim());
            
        }
    });

}
```

}

And finally, this is the error message in the Debugger-

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Customers has no column named Mobile_Number in "INSERT INTO Customers(Mobile_Number,Description,Complaint,First_Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Mobile_Number=Ab Description=a Complaint=a First_Name=a
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Customers has no column named Mobile_Number (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Customers(Mobile_Number,Description,Complaint,First_Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss some spaces while creating the SQL Query string, to solve this change `onCreate()` method to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_COMPLAINT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```